# unity slow down and freeze,became unplayable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

unity stopped working when i hit play in my project am trying to list possible combinations(all type of combinations like 3 letter word, 4 letter word, 5 letter word, upto 10 letter) of randomly generated 10 letter word for that am using nested for loops and i call functions in start function

```
public void CheckingFiveLetter()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < convertStoredLetters.Length; i++) 
             //convertStoredLetters is consonants and vowels which i get at 
    runtime
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < convertStoredLetters.Length; j++) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < convertStoredLetters.Length; k++) 
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < convertStoredLetters.Length; l++)
                {
                    for (int m = 0; m < convertStoredLetters.Length; m++) 
                    {

                        if (i != j && i != k && i != l && i != m  && j != i && j != k && j != l && j != m  && k != i && k != j && k != l && k != m  && l != i && l != j && l != k && l != m  && m != i && m != j && m != k && m != l) 
                        {
                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1));
                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1));
                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1));
                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1));
                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1));


                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1));
                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1));
                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1));
                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1));
                            letterword5.Add (convertStoredLetters.Substring (m, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (l, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (k, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (j, 1) + convertStoredLetters.Substring (i, 1));



                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //checking if the combination is present in the word dictionary or not 
    if present add count
    for (int m = 0; m < letterword5.Count; m++)
    {
        bool Checkfi = wordRan.CheckWord (letterword5 [m].ToLower ());
        if (Checkfi == true) 
        {
            fiveLetterWord.Add (letterword5 [m].ToLower ());

        }

    }
    fi = fiveLetterWord.Distinct ().ToList ();

    wordRan.storeFiveWordCount = fi.Count;
    five.text = "Five Possible words : " + fi.Count.ToString ();
    letterword5.Clear ();
    fiveLetterWord.Clear ();

}
```

similarly for length of words

Comment: You are going to need a decent quantum computer with that many nested for loops.

Comment: I just hope this function is not called in the Update...

Comment: Your cyclomatic complexity is over 28 (recommended 10 max). Simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

Like Vidmantas commented, that many for loops will kill your computer.
I'd recommend trying to simplify it a bit.
Are you trying to generate just one string or all possible strings for a certain amount of letters?

If you just want one string, the best way to handle it is to have one for loop like this:

```
public string RandomWord (int stringLength)
{
    string word = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        int num = random.Range(0, 26);
        char letter = (char)('a' + num);
        word += letter;
    }

    return word;
}
```

*reference:*
https://www.dotnetperls.com/random-lowercase-letter

If you want to get a list of all possible n-letter strings, I'd suggest doing it like this:

```
public string[] WordList (int stringLength)
{
    List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
    List<byte> letterCounter = new List<byte>();
    String word = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        letterCounter.Add(0);
    }

    while (letterCounter[0] < 25)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
        {
            char letter = (char)('a' + letterCounter[i]);
            word += letter;
        }

        wordList.Add(word);
        letterCounter[stringLength]++;

        for (int i = stringLength; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (letterCounter[i] >= 26)
                if (i > 0)
                    letterCounter [i - 1]++;
        }
    }

    return wordList.ToArray();
}
```

If you want to get a list of all dictionary words of a certain length, I'd suggest setting up a dictionary database and getting them from there.

Hope this helped!

Comment: actually its kind of word battle game so i need to know combinations of all length of word (3 letter word, 4 letter word, 5 letter word, 6 letter word, upto 10 letter word) for this what i can do??

Comment: I'm confused, why do you want to know all combinations?
Can you give a bit more explanation of how the game works?
I'm guessing you only want to use dictionary words then?
I'd suggest you create a database of all words that are allowed and make the game compare the input word to the database.

Comment: Are you trying to give the player suggestions on what words they can make with the letters they have or something like that?

Comment: yes giving suggestions to the player on word count. i need to know how many 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 letter  possible words can be formed with the generated 10 letter word

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, you want to give something like a table of the amount of possible 3, 4, 5, ... words you can make from the letters in a given 10 letter word?

I'd suggest breaking the 10 letter word into an array of characters. Then you can take my code for the WordList() and replace the letter picking part with something that cycles through the 10 letter array, adding the words that come out to a new list.
After that, you can compare the contents of the list to your dictionary of allowed words and throw out the ones that are nonsense.
Then you're done!

Comment: yup you understand that is what i want to do let me check with your way

Comment: I have created a new answer that should contain the correct way to do it.

Comment: @AlexchandriyaaP if it works, I'd like to ask you to accept the correct answer as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *While testing the code I realized, this is not exactly the code you're looking for because it gives every possibility. Also ones that use the same letter multiple times. I need to think a bit more on how to improve it. If anyone does know how to do it, feel free to show it.*

Ok, so if I understand your comments correctly, then this should be what you want.

```
public List<string> WordList (int stringLength, string inputWord)
{
    List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
    List<byte> letterCounter = new List<byte>();
    String word = "";

    char[] letters = inputWord.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        letterCounter.Add(0);
    }

    while (letterCounter[0] < 10)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
        {
            char letter = letters[letterCounter[i]];
            word += letter;
        }

        wordList.Add(word);
        letterCounter[stringLength]++;

        for (int i = stringLength; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (letterCounter[i] >= 10)
                if (i > 0)
                    letterCounter [i - 1]++;
        }
    }

    return wordList;
}
```

Now you just have to compare the resulting list to your dictionary and throw out the not-words.

Comment: word = new string(word + letter); here i cant add string

Comment: Ah, sorry.
I guess it should be word = word + letter.ToString(); then.
I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: am getting this error in that specific line error : the best overloaded method match for string.string(char*) has some invalid arguments

Comment: What if you change it to just word + letter? So ignore the .ToString?

Comment: both word + letter and word + letter.tOstring() throws same error

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code, but while doing so I realized it's not the code you're looking for. You only want to use each letter once, and that's not what this code does. I'll get back to you, but I'll have to think on how to fix that.